# watchOS background task crashes on setTaskCompleted

Tags: wcsession, watchos-4, wkrefreshbackgroundtask

In my watch extension delegate `init` function, I set up KVO observers on the `WCSession`:

```
if WCSession.isSupported() {
  let defaultSession = WCSession.default
  defaultSession.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "activationState", 
                             options: [.old, .new], 
                             context: &ExtensionDelegate.wcSessionKVOcontext)
  defaultSession.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "hasContentPending", 
                             options: [.old, .new], 
                             context: &ExtensionDelegate.wcSessionKVOcontext)
}
```

In order to complete all watch background tasks, this calls the function

```
  override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if context == &ExtensionDelegate.wcSessionKVOcontext {
      printStatusChanges(keyPath: keyPath, change: change)
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.completeAllTasksIfReady()
      }
    }
  }
```

with

```
  private func completeAllTasksIfReady() {
    let session = WCSession.default
    // the session's properties only have valid values if the session is activated, so check that first
    if session.activationState == .activated && !session.hasContentPending {
            if wcBackgroundTasks.isEmpty {
                print("No background tasks")
            } else {
                wcBackgroundTasks.forEach { $0.setTaskCompleted() }
                print("\(wcBackgroundTasks.count) connectivity background tasks completed")
            }
      wcBackgroundTasks.removeAll()
    }
  }
```

Normally, this works fine.
However I had a crash with the following log:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1db2eda8 __abort_with_payload + 24
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1db2ae60 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 60
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1db2ae24 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 0
3   WatchKit                        0x2ddfce86 -[WKRefreshBackgroundTask setTaskCompleted] + 414
4   Watch Extension                 0x00037258 closure #1 in ExtensionDelegate.completeAllTasksIfReady() + 209496 (ExtensionDelegate.swift:196)
5   Watch Extension                 0x000372b0 thunk for @callee_guaranteed (@owned WKRefreshBackgroundTask) -> (@error @owned Error) + 209584 (ExtensionDelegate.swift:0)
6   Watch Extension                 0x0003af08 partial apply for thunk for @callee_guaranteed (@owned WKRefreshBackgroundTask) -> (@error @owned Error) + 225032 (ExtensionDelegate.swift:0)
7   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00525350 0x2fc000 + 2265936
8   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00433b7c 0x2fc000 + 1276796
9   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00304060 0x2fc000 + 32864
10  Watch Extension                 0x00036eec ExtensionDelegate.completeAllTasksIfReady() + 208620 (ExtensionDelegate.swift:196)
11  Watch Extension                 0x000350d4 closure #1 in ExtensionDelegate.observeValue(forKeyPath:of:change:context:) + 200916 (ExtensionDelegate.swift:108)
12  Watch Extension                 0x0000993c _T0Ieg_IeyB_TR + 22844 (AlertManager.swift:0)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x1d9d3456 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x1d9d3432 _dispatch_client_callout + 6
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x1d9e3604 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 858
16  CoreFoundation                  0x1df7db1e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 10
17  CoreFoundation                  0x1df7b73c __CFRunLoopRun + 932
18  CoreFoundation                  0x1dec7660 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 534
19  GraphicsServices                0x1fb7ab3e GSEventRunModal + 94
20  UIKit                           0x24746604 UIApplicationMain + 156
21  libxpc.dylib                    0x1dcf7b14 _xpc_objc_main + 586
22  libxpc.dylib                    0x1dcf94a8 xpc_main + 154
23  Foundation                      0x1e9b2cf2 service_connection_handler + 0
24  PlugInKit                       0x2525c06e -[PKService run] + 676
25  WatchKit                        0x2de1b036 main + 162
26  libdyld.dylib                   0x1da2e782 start + 2
```

Obviously, the crash happens when `setTaskCompleted` is called in one of the `WKRefreshBackgroundTask` tasks.

But what could be the reason, or how to debug this?

Comment: Not sure why it would matter, but you could try using $0.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false). That is the new function as of watchOS 4

Comment: @Zachary Bell: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try. The problem, of course, is that this apparently a very rare crash.

Comment: I can't prove it, but I think there are still a few bugs on Apple's side in memory management and background task handling.  I suspect that the watch sometimes reaches memory exhaustion, leading to background crashes.  Very hard to debug though.  A watch reboot has repaired several issues here.

Comment: @Cobra Thanks for your comment. Do you think it is worth it to send a bug report, if it is not reproducible at all?

Comment: It doesn't hurt.  However, Apple will ask for details to reproduce, so having at least a log will give them something.  They will at least mark it as a duplicate of something else if they already are aware of it, so you will know they are investigating.  In my experience, you may hear nothing after that for a very long time though...

Comment: Submitted, #39968826

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My fault. Apple replied to my bug report with:

> This issue behaves as intended based on the following:
>   -  this is an assert put in place to make sure that the same task is not completed more than once
>   - this is indicated by  "called on `WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask: 0x16e7b230` that's already
>   been completed”
>   - this likely points to a bug (or bugs) in the project’s code and not with the SDK/API

I thus double checked if it is possible in my code that for a `WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask` function `setTaskCompleted` is called more than once. This is indeed the case:

When I started to develop my watch extension, I copied [Apple demo code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/QuickSwitch/Listings/QuickSwitch_WatchKit_Extension_ExtensionDelegate_swift.html). It contains the following function:

```
func handle(_ backgroundTasks: Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>) {
    for backgroundTask in backgroundTasks {
        if let wcBackgroundTask = backgroundTask as? WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask {
            // store a reference to the task objects as we might have to wait to complete them
            self.wcBackgroundTasks.append(wcBackgroundTask)
        } else {
            // immediately complete all other task types as we have not added support for them
            backgroundTask.setTaskCompleted()
        }
    }
    completeAllTasksIfReady()
}
```

Here, a `WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask` that should be handled is stored in an array `wcBackgroundTasks`. Later in `completeAllTasksIfReady()` all tasks in this array are completed by `wcBackgroundTasks.forEach { $0.setTaskCompleted() }`.

My fault was that I stored my `WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask` in this array (and called later `setTaskCompleted` for it) and handled it immediately and set `setTaskCompleted`. So this was called twice.
Thanks to the Apple engineer who found this.

Comment: I'm impressed.  I've had cases where Apple's response was very slow.  This is a nice response from them!